# Using reflection to reduce enum boilerplate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reflection, enums

Recently, I found this handy little snippet of code to get the string representation of an enum, even when associated values are present:

```
enum XXX {
    case a
    case b
    case c(Int)

    private var typeStr: String {
        guard let label = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first?.label else { 
            return .init(describing: self) 
        }
        return label
    }
}
```

This is pretty clever. Could reflection also be used to reduce boilerplate like this init function?

```
init?(rawValue: String?)
{
    guard let val = rawValue?.lowercased() else {
        return nil
    }
    switch val {
        case "a", "1a": self = .a
        case "b", "1b": self = .b
        case "c", "1c": self = .c(1)
        default: return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done with Mirror.

Answer (score 0):

To use init by rawValue you need to conform to `RawRepresentable`. And it's a good idea to conform to `CaseIterable`, since we gonna need a set of `allCases`.

```
enum SomeEnum: CaseIterable, RawRepresentable{
    case a
    case b
    case c(Int)

    typealias AllCases = [SomeEnum]
    static let allCases: [SomeEnum] = [.a, .b, .c(0)]
    static let allCasesStr = { SomeEnum.allCases.map{ $0.typeStr } }
    typealias RawValue = String

    var rawValue: String {
        return self.typeStr
    }

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        let allCasesStrLocal = SomeEnum.allCasesStr()
        let allCasesLocal = SomeEnum.allCases
        print(allCasesStrLocal)
        guard let i = allCasesStrLocal.firstIndex(of: rawValue), allCasesLocal.indices.contains(i)  else { return nil }
            print(i)
            self = allCasesLocal[i]
        }

    private var typeStr: String {
        guard let label = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first?.label else {
            return .init(describing: self)
        }
        return label
    }
}

// Tests
let caseA = SomeEnum.a
let caseAWithRawInit = SomeEnum.init(rawValue: "a")!
let caseBWithRawInit = SomeEnum.init(rawValue: "b")!
let caseC = SomeEnum.c(123)
let caseCWithRawInit = SomeEnum.init(rawValue: "c")!
print(caseA, caseAWithRawInit, caseBWithRawInit, caseC, caseCWithRawInit)
// "a a b c(123) c(0)\n"
```

Works fine in Playground (Xcode 10). You may try to avoid using some local vars (`allCasesStrLocal`, `allCasesLocal`) and extra assignments, but there might be some catches.